# Selecting an IoU and confidence threshold for evaluation of model performance

Tags: machine-learning

mAP is commonly used to evaluate the performance of object detection models. However, there are two variables that need to be set when calculating mAP:

- confidence threshold
- IoU threshold

Just to clarify, confidence threshold is the minimum score that the model will consider the prediction to be a true prediction (otherwise it will ignore this prediction entirely). IoU threshold is the minimum overlap between ground truth and prediction boxes for the prediction to be considered a true positive.

Setting both of these thresholds to be low would result in a greater mAP. However, the low thresholds would most likely be inconsistent with the mAP scores from other studies. How does one select, **and justify**, these threshold values?

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: I think using validation dataset to adjust these values is just fine. I see these values are hyperparamters which should be adjusted. See [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/issues/8615#issuecomment-1188719094).

Comment: We can discuss about Non Max Suppression (NMS) values or post-NMS values when doing model evaluation. When you run detect.py from yolov5 for example, the conf and IoU threshold arguments passed to the script are fed into the NMS algorithm. Then other thresholds are used post-NMS to compute Precision, Recall and mAP by, say, pycoctools, or the evaluation that yolov5 offers. I still need to wrap my head around this as well.

Answer (score 0):

In Yolov5, we do NMS on the outputs of network, then calculate mAP. So, there is a conf_thres and an iou_thres in NMS to filter some boxes, these are set to 0.001 and 0.6, see: https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/2373d5470e386a0c63c6ab77fbee6d699665e27b/val.py#L103.

When calculating mAP, we set iou threshold to 0.5 for mAP@0.5, or 0.5 to 0.95 with step 0.05 for mAP@0.5:0.95.

I guess the way of calculating mAP in Yolov5 is aligned to other framework. If I'm wrong, please correct me.